# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S10 mobile hotspot cut out after exactly one hour?

Tags: samsung, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, mobile-network

I have an issue where if I turn on my hotspot it will automatically stop working after exactly one hour, every time. I have tested this with a stopwatch several times to confirm this is the case. It's becoming a real pain because I'm always on the go and need to tether my mobile internet to my other devices for work purposes.

- I have reset my network settings.
- I made sure the `Turn off when no device connected for` setting is on **Never timeout**.
- The system software is fully up-to-date.

There has to be some setting or issue somewhere causing it. Has anyone else ever experienced this? I can't figure it out and would super appreciate any help. Are there any logs I can look at?

The way this issue presents itself is odd. The connected devices lose the hotspot connection entirely, however, the hotspot toggle on the Samsung phone is still set to On. If I search for the hotspot I can still find it, and when I try to reconnect it will take a little longer than usual and eventually say "Connected - No Internet". I then have to go back to the Samsung and toggle the hotspot off/on to get it working on the other devices again.

I'm using the exact same sim card I had in my Huawei 20 Pro before I upgraded to Samsung and this was never an issue on that phone. It seems unique to my Samsung.

Comment: Is this when you are still or when you are driving ?

Comment: Always when stationary working in one spot

Comment: Do you have a VPN running ?

Comment: No VPN running this end

Comment: I do have a VPN profile installed on the phone from a VPN app i have but the VPN is never switched on. But i can uninstall the VPN app and delete the VPN profile from the phone to be sure it's not that and re-test.

Comment: OK so I've just been in to see one of the people in the Samsung shop and asked the question directly. They said that a recent update in the system software has caused this. Apparently, Samsung deliberately put a one hour timeout on the hotspot because people were complaining that it was eating all their data! What the actual *#@!??

Comment: I'm finding this really difficult to believe to be true. I'm now in a queue with Samsung support so i can get an answer from a technician.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than listing them one by one in the comments.  These are some of the possible causes for the hotspot to stop.

1. Default setup option in Samsung to timeout is after 1 hour.
2. VPN app running that may reset it when it reconnects to the internet.
3. Lock / Limitation by ISP.  ISPs in some countries are very strict about this.
4. WIFI interference or Out-Of-Range may also stop hotspot.
5. Battery Saving Mode may drop hotspot
6. Rate-limited mobile plan can do it too.
7. Connecting to a Wifi network will stop hotspot.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I can confirm that 2-7 are not an issue on this side. I am curious about what you mean by Default setup option in Samsung to timeout is after 1 hour. Are you aware of this as being the case or rather is it a suggestion that it could be a possibility? Also I've received 3 upvotes so far for this question so I imagine others are also experiencing this. If there are any settings you think I can look at specific to point 1. please let do me know.

Comment: I have seen this on 3 different mobiles, but I believe that you have already set this to never timeout.